# How can I convert incoming checkbox values into one hidden field value?

Tags: php

My submitting page includes some checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="p_queue_type[]" id="p_queue_type_all" value="All">
<input type="checkbox" name="p_queue_type[]" id="p_queue_type_CR" value="CR" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="p_queue_type[]" id="p_queue_type_FPU" value="FPU">
<input type="checkbox" name="p_queue_type[]" id="p_queue_type_HOLD" value="HOLD" checked>
```

My processing page needs to convert any of the incoming "p_queue_type[]" values into one hidden field (this example desired outcome assumes "CR" and "HOLD" are checked):

```
<input type="hidden" name="p_queue_type[]" value="['CR','HOLD']" />
```

I'm trying to incorporate this functionality into an existing loop that iterates over the incoming `$_POST` array:

```
    foreach ($attributes as $field => $value){
        echo('<input type="hidden" name="'.$field.'" id="'.$field.'" value="'.$value.'" />');
    };
```

But this results in a useless hidden field value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="p_queue_type[]" value="Array" />
```

Comment: try this ``<input type="checkbox" name="p_queue_type[all]" id="p_queue_type_all" value="All">
<input type="checkbox" name="p_queue_type[cr]" id="p_queue_type_CR" value="CR" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="p_queue_type[fpu]" id="p_queue_type_FPU" value="FPU">
<input type="checkbox" name="p_queue_type[hold]" id="p_queue_type_HOLD" value="HOLD" checked>``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
foreach ($attributes as $field => $value){
    $value = is_array($value) ? '[' . implode(',', $value) . ']' : $value;
    echo('<input type="hidden" name="'.$field.'" id="'.$field.'" value="'.$value.'" />');
};
```

It converts the php array to an html friendly array string

Comment: That does exactly what I asked for. Thanks Jonathan.